# Use Wikipedia API to get the most read articles within a certain time range?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Given some integer `n` and a date `d`, I'd like to use the Wikipedia API to obtain the `n` most viewed articles in the time between `d` and the current date. Is this possible, and if so, how?

What I have tried so far is the following:

1. Use https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2017/05/01 . The problems with this approach are that firstly, this seems to support no other value than `n = 1000` and secondly, it aggregates views only for a single day and not an arbitrary time range.
2. Use the [query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query) action with list `allpages` (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages) to obtain all articles, but I do not know how to filter the result such that only the most viewed articles are included.

I also checked https://stats.wikimedia.org/ but didn't find anything helpful there.

Comment: Were you ever able to get a woking solution for this problem (top-N articles in time range)?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't appear to be available through the Pageviews API at present. You can find the most-viewed articles for a given day or a given month, but not for an arbitrary time frame. See the [REST API docs](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/) for the different options available, and also see the [Pageviews API page on Wikitech](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/AQS/Pageviews), which gives an example for finding the most viewed articles in a given month. (Slightly worryingly, the most-viewed-articles-per-month syntax doesn't seem to be documented on the API docs page.)

You can also get the pageview data through the Action API (api.php), as Tgr says in his comment below, but the data is the same as for the REST API.

You might want to ask on the [wikitech-l email list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wikitech-l), which is watched by the Wikimedia devs. They'll be able to tell you if this is possible a different way, and if not, why the feature isn't available.

Comment: Pageview data is availabe in the action API via [prop=pageviews](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Extension:PageViewInfo#query+pageviews)/[list=mostviewed](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Extension:PageViewInfo#query+mostviewed)/[meta=siteviews](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Extension:PageViewInfo#query+siteviews), but it's just a redressing of the REST API data.

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked that part before I answered, as it's been quite a while since I investigated WMF pageviews. I've edited my answer to make it less wrong. :)